# selecting value from “bootstrap dropdown” in selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to click on a specific value from a drop-down list, the code in the IDE selenium works if the div had the "Select" attribute, but this div does not.
I don't have access and permission to change the HTML or CSS structure, I have access just to Selenium to test.

The dropdown structure is implemented as follows:

```
<div class="selectize-dropdown-content">
  <div class="option" data-selectable="" data-value="female">Female</div>
  <div class="option active" data-selectable="" data-value="male">Male</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can accomplish it by just simulating "clicks" instead of trying to use Selenium's `select`.

```
click | css=div.selectize-dropdown-content
click | css=div[data-value='male']
```

Answer (score 1):

click | //div[@class='selectize-dropdown-content']/div[contains(text(),'Female')]